# Is there an equivalent of from tokenize import pseudoprog.match in Python 3?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert an ancient library to Python 3.5 that is supposed to parse C++ into .NET which can be called via Python via PythonNET, and using PInvokes so it can also run on Linux https://github.com/andyhebear/sharppy/tree/master/src .  It's called SharpPY and hasn't been updated in years.  It calls another library Cheetah that depends on a lot of other ancient libraries.  The one I can't find a substitute for so far is `from tokenize import pseudoprog` where it is only used for 1 function, `match = pseudoprog.match(self.src(), self.pos())` I'm just looking for an equivalent in Python 3.5.  Once I'm all done I can post the updated code on GIT as it has been a real pain to convert over.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the source for [`tokenize.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/tokenize.py) between 2.7 and 3.5?

Comment: your question would be better and would fit within SO's model a bit better if you describe what the function you need does.  So, "how can I replace this function," fits better here than "What tool should I use for x".

Comment: What you've discovered here is that depending on implementation details of builtin python modules is a bad idea. Perhaps instead of trying to find the corresponding implementation detail in 3.5, you should work out whether what it is doing can be expressed in a public API.

Comment: All good points.  Looking at the 2.7 source code:
generate_tokens(readline) is a generator that breaks a stream of
text into Python tokens.  It accepts a readline-like method which is called
repeatedly to get the next line of input (or "" for EOF).  It generates
5-tuples with these members:

    the token type (see token.py)
    the token (a string)
    the starting (row, column) indices of the token (a 2-tuple of ints)
    the ending (row, column) indices of the token (a 2-tuple of ints)
    the original line (string)

Comment: Comparing the Python 3.5 and 2.7 code it appears the only instance comparable is `pseudomatch` which is in lines 599-601.  `while pos < max:
            pseudomatch = _compile(PseudoToken).match(line, pos)` still digging here.  Looks like @Eric has a good idea here as the code matches the lines 383-386 of the 2.7 version.

Comment: I'm just curious, why not just use SWIG or cppsharp?

Comment: @denfromufa I just downloaded cppsharp today do you suggest using it?  Is it easy?  SWIG had a bunch of interface files to write so I was searching for something easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Eric I think I found the solution:

Python 2.7:

```
from tokenize import pseudoprog
match = pseudoprog.match(self.src(), self.pos())
```

Python 3.5:

```
import tokenize
from tokenize import _compile
match = _compile(self).match(self.src(), self.pos())
```

Comment: Those don't look equivalent to me. I suspect you need `PseudoToken`

Comment: Sorry I showed only the changes needed in the file I was using - it does pass a token

Comment: I.e. both routines require a `psuedotoken` input so the code change outlined works for conversion between 2.7 and 3.5.